# Alternatives to Visual Studio Test Professional

Tags: testing

I'm searching for alternatives for Visual Studio Test Professional. I only want to manage test plans as comfortable as possible. A Connection to a TFS is not necessary.
Such Feautures like recording video and so on would be nice.

The test suite is not for the developer. It is for the testing team.

regards Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete) from SmartBear is the best test suite I know of.  It has some missing features that Visual Studio Test Professional, but it definitely exceeds Test Professional in features that are available.